# Проблемы с gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, espresso, юнит-тесты

Есть тестовый метод:

```
@Test
public void scrollToItemBelowFold_checkItsText() {
    // First scroll to the position that needs to be matched and click on it.
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerView))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(ITEM_BELOW_THE_FOLD, click()));

    // Match the text in an item below the fold and check that it's displayed.
    String itemElementText = mActivityRule.getActivity().getResources().getString(
            R.string.item_element_text) + String.valueOf(ITEM_BELOW_THE_FOLD);
    onView(withText(itemElementText)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

В котором присутствует

```
Test class showcasing some {@link RecyclerViewActions} from Espresso
```

Пробую запилить её в gradle по разному:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
```

`
но увы не получается, выдаёт ошибки

> androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
>       androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'

Подскажите, как можно исправить? А то подобные [решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ) мимо.

Comment: какие ошибки выдает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну с таким [подходом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609084/211117) можно из программиста превратиться в мангальщика, шашлычника) как Вам уже будет угодно) Если каждый раз бросать всё на пол пути, далеко не продвинетесь, ну а теперь к вопросу:

При создании нового проекта, у Вас сразу же в Вашей build.gradle создаётся Espesso support, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
 androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Как Вы успели заметить он дополняет в себя следующие groups.
Далее, для работы Вам понадобятся некоторые из компайлов, которые я предлагаю добавить вместе со следующими дополнениями примерно следующим образом:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

Можно конечно прописать и без exclude, но скорей всего в этом и кроется Ваша проблема.

Также если Вы собираетесь тестировать intents/webview то можно добавить:

```
// add this for intent mocking support
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'

// add this for webview testing support
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
```

Ну и последнее замечание, смотрите чтобы Ваши версии везде совпадали. Для наглядности:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
```

Также если Вы тестируете Recycler то можно добавить следующее:

```
//RecyclerView
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Подводя вывод, можете попробовать другие инструменты, такие как calabash к примеру. Пробуйте, и всё обязательно получится)

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Смысл ответа состоял в том, что основной упор надо делать таки на разработке, а не на том, чтобы отлаживать тестирование тестировщика :) Или не дай бог еще отлаживать тесты тестирования тестировщика.

Comment: @Barmaley Ну на сколько мне известно, хорошей практикой является написание тестов, а уж потом сама разработка.

Comment: @Morozov эту практику придумали хреновые манагеры проектов, которые так пытаются контролировать разработчиков. Начнете работать в индустрии поймете, что писать тесты это зло для разработчика и благо для менеджера проекта или тимлида

Comment: @Barmaley я всё таки с Вами не соглашусь) потому как если в процессе своей разработки у Вас что то ломается, то потом поиск проблемы занимает куда намного больше времени. И да, оно упрощает работу других отраслей, но это же не есть плохо) тот же cucumber который сокращает Ваши пояснения в разы.

Answer (score 2):

Я в таких случаях тупо выкидываю инструмент. Поясню свою концепцию, а именно:

> обучение владению инструментом не должно быть дороже обучения собственно основному ремеслу

Ну то есть мне приносят новенький блестящий инструмент, а именно *The Espresso testing framework*, я с удовольствием ставлю его и пытаюсь воспользоваться. Ну конечно, с первого раза инструмент не заработает, вчитываемся в мануал - еще попытка, тоже не заводится. Еще 2-3 итерации и все - я выкидываю инструмент.

Напомню таки, что Espresso это инструмент для тестирования, а не для разработки это не новая либа, не новый паттерн, не новый фреймворк - а всего лишь инструмент тестирования. То есть он не создает новую функциональность, он не создает новый UI, ничего не создает. Он просто инструмент для тестирования.

Ну типа у тебя есть классный новый мангал, на котором ты классно умеешь жарить шашлыки. К тебе подкатывает мужичок и говорит: слышь, у меня есть супер-пупер градусник для мяса, с помощью которого ты будешь делать шашлыки еще лучше - попробуй пожалуйста. И ты пробуешь, и обнаруживаешь, что не можешь включить этот мудреный градусник - там че-то кнопок многовато. Твои действия - правильно, ты выкинешь градусник, ибо орава народу ждет шашлыки и стучат вилками о тарелочки и орут: "подавай шашлыки!".

Резюме: выкидывайте к черту этот Espresso и займитесь шашлыками :)

С Новым Годом!